# Woocommerce How to use my own CSS

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have de-enqued the WooCommerce default CSS styles.

I also enqued my own CSS style .

Now the question is how will I know which class names to use in my own CSS for styling the WooCommerce?

Will I copy the original CSS to my own CSS and then edit them? I don't know LESS and the original CSS is in compreseed form making it hard to edit it.

2ndly, is using the Firebug tool and then copying the CSS used is a good method to go with?

I want to know the most easiest method of using my own CSS on the WC templates.

Thank you

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [Procssor](http://tools.maxcdn.com/procssor/) to make the CSS more legible.